# How do i run the functions randomly in jython script?

Tags: java, python, jython, grinder

```
class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
        user1()
        user2()
        user3()
        user4()
```

How do I execute the users randomly in jython, to run in grinder tool?

Comment: Exactly one execution per user (shuffle them / Martijn's answer), or execute a random user each time this is called (take a random one / Lionel's answer)?

Comment: nice to know..valuable information.. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the functions in a list (without calling them), then use `random.shuffle`:

```
import random

class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
        users = [user1, user2, user3, user4]
        random.shuffle(users)
        for user in users:
            user()
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know jython, but if you want a random choice, this should work

```
import random
class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
        func = random.choice([user1, user2, user3, user3])
        func()
```

Comment: I think this approach is a little more flexible than Martijn's